# Libreoffice 5.2. How to disable the new toolbar having only close button?

Tags: libreoffice

After upgrading to Libreoffice 5.2 in Ubuntu, there is a new tool bar on the top with only one icon, ie close button in its right side.
How to disable this toolbar?

[image: new toolbar with close button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a toolbar, this is the menubar and you can't remove it.
The problem is that this menubar is missing the menu-entries.
Here same issue:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2335910&page=2

Comment: @Zanna: I believe this is meant to be an answer: it explains why OP's issue cannot be solved (apparently).